Is it guaranteed that std::chrono::steady_clock always has equal tick intervals?
Are steady_clock's tick intervals stable independent of CPU throttling, load, etc? Is it reliable for measurement intervals between different events?
Will two different PC's have the same steady_clock's intervals?

In C++, every clock has a member type period, an "std::ratio type representing the tick period of the clock, in seconds," as you can read on cppreference.com. The ratio is a compile-time constant, meaning the tick period is a compile time constant. In that way, it is independent from the underlying hardware and only dependent on your C++ implementation.
Of course in a real-world sense, meaning if you compare it to an atomic clock, it will have jitter, drift, etc. But again, as cppreference describes it:

The time points of this clock cannot decrease as physical time moves forward and the time between ticks of this clock is constant. This clock is not related to wall clock time (for example, it can be time since last reboot), and is most suitable for measuring intervals.

Meaning, it's as steady as the underlying hardware can manage.

So, if my app freezes, the counter of steady_clock will continue to tick with the same intervals, right?

@Robotex the counter is based on a hardware clock; not sure which one is currently in use on major OSes, HPET, TSC, ACPI PM timer, APIC timer, something else. Whatever it is, you would need the freeze the entire OS long enough to overflow the timer for it to stop working properly.
